# Using a webservice with vbscript - "An operations error occurred."

Tags: c#, iis-7, vbscript, web-services

I've been fiddling a bit with c# webservices and vbscript. Things work fine if I trigger the services manually through IE directly on the webserver, but when I try to run the same service from a vbscript it throws a "An operations error occurred." exception.

The service is pretty simple, all it does is create a computer object in Active Directory.

```
DirectoryEntry Container = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://ldapgw/" + LDAPLocation); 
DirectoryEntries ComputerOU = Container.Children; 
DirectoryEntry ComputerObject = ComputerOU.Add("CN=" + ComputerName, "computer"); 
ComputerObject.InvokeSet("sAMAccountName", ComputerName); 
ComputerObject.InvokeSet("description", "Reserved"); 
ComputerObject.InvokeSet("userAccountControl", 4128); 
ComputerObject.CommitChanges();
```

It's triggered this way:

```
Set soap = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")  
soap "POST", URL, false, username, password  
soap.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8" 
soap.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", nsURL + service  
soap.send xml
```

I'm guessing this has something to do with permissions, but I can't figure out what. I'm using impersonation and if I output `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` it seems to be running as the correct user which has the needed rights in AD.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

try keeping your code inside this block

```
Using HostingEnvironment.Impersonate()
....you code....
End Using
```

This will impersonate the account from the apppool when authenticating with AD. If the app pool identity has the right access to AD, it will work the usual.

Comment: I'm giving you a bounty on this, as you totally solved my problem with one line of code. Gotta wait a day, tho.